# HTML required attr changing layout?

Tags: forms, validation, input, required, required-field

I was looking around on CodeMyUI.com and came across this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJQORQ.
It's a very cool animated form but there is one thing I can't get my head around. If I change `<input type="text" required />` to `<input type="text"/>`, it changes the layout. As far as I know is the required attribute not supposed to change the layout of the input field.
Does anybody have any idea's of why this is happening?

Comment: check the source, there may be a hidden element (`visibility:hidden`, as opposed to `display:none`) used for validation on that generated form.

Comment: the only display is a `display:block` and that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: It is weird, but if there is intermediate software generating the form, it is understandable.  Real estate may be required for validation messaging, and there may even be something as odd as extra space in differing layouts.  If this is raw HTML, then I don't see how the layout would change, but always willing to learn! ;-)

Comment: If you inspect the element you should find there is a `label input:valid + .label-text` CSS selector - I *suspect* that not having `required` makes the `:valid` not apply. Well, I think that's where it goes wrong.

Comment: Very interesting, but i think you're right. If i remove the `:valid` and just add the code to the already existin `.label-text` it works fine without required. Thanks a lot man!